# How to overcome the square bracket issue with lambda expression C++

Tags: c++, lambda

Here's a Function implementation from Bjarne's book

```
typedef double Fct(double);

Function::Function(Fct f, double r1, double r2, Point xy, int count, double xscale, double yscale)
```

and here's the code creating Function e

```
Function e{[n](double x) {return expcalc(x,n);},rmin,rmax,orig,200,xscale,yscale };
```

The line above gives the following error when compiling:

```
No instance of constructor Function::Function matches the argument list.
```

Note 1: this function is used to calculate exp(x) using Taylor series

Note 2: the code compiles if I remove n from lambda's square brackets

Note 3: Bjarne's used the exact same implementation in his book, not sure why it's not working here

Note 4: I'm using MVS19 community version

Comment: @S.M. Yes it can, but the syntax is a bit obscure :  auto lambda = [](double x) {return 2.0 * x; }; Fct fun = +lambda;

Comment: I need to keep n

Comment: Bjarne used THIS EXACT implementation and it works in his case

Comment: @zizou: It is a duplicate. Lambdas can be converted to a function pointer, but only if they don't capture anything.

Comment: @PepijnKramer: It's a compile error; "life cycle" is irrelevant.

Comment: this is the whole code
for (int n = 0 ; n<50 ; ++n){
 Function e{[n](double x) {return expcalc(x,n);},rmin,rmax,orig,200,xscale,yscale };
}

Comment: @NicolBolas I missed that bit, you're right. Then just use std::function<double (double)> instead of a function pointer.

Comment: I copied the whole thing from Bjarne's book, why it's not working if he used it ?

Comment: Bjarne can also make mistakes ;)

Comment: Oh and (implementations of) compilers too

Comment: @zizou: Books can have typos. The language is what it is regardless.

Comment: the point is this Function is not the std::function, another point is this is not about pointers. Off course everyone makes mistakes, but the idea here this implementation of lambda in this is inside a loop, so it is taking the value n. So here there's no room for suspicion about typos or whatever.